# How to solve this integral easily: $\int \frac{x\cdot \sqrt[3]{x+2}}{x+\sqrt[3]{x+2}} dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral $$\int\frac{x\cdot \sqrt[3]{x+2}}{x+\sqrt[3]{x+2}} dx$$
I can do it by brute force (means using a substitution then long division and then substitutions again) but it's too long (suspiciously long solution). Is there any better way to solve it? I guess it should be. If you could provide me with the process that leads to the answer that would really help.

Comment: From the looks of [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%28x%2B2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2F%28x%2B%28x%2B2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29), I'm not sure this integral can be solved "easily."

Comment: I don't know whether this is any better than what you already have (since you haven't told us what exactly you already have), but I'd substitute $u=\root3\of{x+2}$, $x=u^3-2$, $dx=3u^2\,du$ to turn it into a rational function, and take it from there.

Comment: What I already have is the solution below (sultan). :)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\sqrt[3]{x+2}=u$ therefore $\frac{du}{dx} =\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}}$

Your integral will become : 3$\int\dfrac{u^3(u^3-2)}{u^3+u-2}du $

= $3\int [u^3+ \dfrac{5u-2}{4(u^2+u+2)}-u-\dfrac{1}{4(u-1)}]du$

=$3\int u^3du + \dfrac{3}{4}\int(\dfrac{5(2u+1)}{2(u^2+u+2)}-\dfrac{9}{2(u^2+u+2)})du - \dfrac{3}{4}\int\dfrac{1}{u-1}du -3\int u.du$

Now you can  easily see that differentiation of $u^2+u+2 = 2u+1$ so you can substitute $u^2+u+2 = t$ then proceed you will get your result.

In case of further clarification do let me know...

Comment: That first formula for $du$ can't be right. To begin with, it needs to have a $dx$ in it somewhere, but that's not all.

Comment: If $u = \sqrt[3]{x+2}$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}}$

Comment: Even Wolfram Alpha says so... =P http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+cube+root+(x%2B2)&t=sfmtb01

Comment: The edit is better, although the $dx$ is still missing.